# Android App Crashing On Phablets But Working Perfectly On Phones

Tags: java, android

I just released an app for Android and the person who hired me on to make it keeps saying that the app is crashing on his and his brothers' phablets (they have different phones, one Galaxy Note 2 and one Galaxy Mega 6.3). They both run 4.4, so I'm baffled as to why it's working on my Galaxy S5, my Moto G, and my brother's Galaxy S4 perfectly without a single crash, but not on theirs. The stack traces are always NullPointerExceptions, and once I fixed the first one at onCreateOptionsMenu another one arose in the Parse FindCallback. Again, these issues don't exist at all on normal phones. I just need some clarification as to why this would be happening on one device and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

You may have some assets which are missing for the larger devices if you've been putting things in restrictive directories.  Make sure that all your assets will resolve to something valid on the larger devices.

Answer (score 1):

> I just need some clarification as to why this would be happening on
>   one device and not the other.

Because Android devices differ greatly - from the obvious screen sizes and API versions, to manufacturer OS modifications.

The only way to debug and fix an issue happening on a particular device (or class of devices) is to get your hands on it and test. Have your boss lend you his phone.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a remote job so that's not an option, but thank you in any case. I just wanted to make sure that this is a somewhat normal occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The onCreateOptionsMenu error could be related to the hardware navigation button of the Samsung Note. Are you sure you saw that same error on the Samsung Mega? I really doubt that you did.

The second error is not due to the size of the screen, but most likely due to the cell phone network condition, or poor wifi conditions. You should always test for a connection that is going to be slow and have high latency just like it can happen in the real world.

Comment: Actually you're absolutely right it was only on the Note. I do check whether there is an active connection or not, but not for a slow network connection...could you point me towards a resource for that? Thank you for your response in any case, it really helped.

Comment: On the emulator/DDMS, there are some settings to artificially slow down the network connection. I've also seen a free tool offered by AT&T that can help simulate a bad cell phone network connection. I believe it's this tool: http://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer